# How do I breed the Cyclops dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

The Cyclops dragon is a new dragon, and I have no idea how to breed one. Unlike most dragons, it isn't listed with an element combination to give me a clue.

How can I breed this dragon?

Comment: I used the heart dragon with the rust dragon and got a cyclops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While any combination of Metal, Water, and Lightning has a chance of creating a Cyclops Dragon, I [have it on good authority](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/posts/1053) that the statistically fastest pairings to get one are:

- Magnetic and (Seaweed or Swamp)
- Cactus and Rust

Ash and Quicksilver has been a popular combo, although statistically the above listed pairings are the most likely to produce the Cyclops with the least amount of wasted time.

The breeding time is 33 hours without the breeding speed upgrade or 26 hours, 24 minutes with.  Do note that this is not a time-limited dragon, so don't consider this a priority over other, less available dragons.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but isn't the breeding time 33 hours for a non-upgraded breeding? That's what the Wikia and the Breeding Sandbox show.

Comment: @Fluttershy, yep, you're right!  Stand by while I fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [Dragonvale Wikia on Breeding](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Breeding):

The Cyclops Dragon is able to be bred with a combination of three elements: Metal, Water, and Lightning.

So breeding a metal/water hybrid with lightning, or a lightning/metal hybrid with water, or any combination of the above, have a chance to result in a Cyclops dragon.

For more possible combos you can try the [Dragonvale Breeding Sandbox](http://www.2084.org/dragonvale/breeding-sandbox/)

Answer (score 1):

I used the Breeding Sandbox which suggested Chrome and Plasma as one of the potential combinations.  It was my first time using this combination and I figured it would take several tries, but I was wrong.  First time using Chrome and Plasma on the island gave my a 33 hour incubation time which I know is Cyclops.

Comment: This isn't the place to ask your question.  I have removed that from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Video showing how at youtube.com

To Breed:
Any combination of metal, water and lightning